# Convertir parametros de un array javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito una funcion que me cambie los parametros que acepta un arreglo el acepta 'abbreviation' y 'description' tiene que leer  'optionStringValue' y 'optionStringText'

Tengo un Select2 que me deberia de cargar todos los meses del año pero no los carga porque el array que tengo acepta otros parametros que no acepta el LoadDataSelect que tengo

este el codigo que tengo

eso me deberia de cargar los meses

```
pLoadDataSelect($('#select_mes'),fGetArrayMonth(),{
                'optionStringValue' : 1,
                'optionStringText' : 1,
                'functionData' : fDataSelectCountBudget
            });
```

De este arreglo

```
function fGetArrayMonth() {

    var array = [];

    array.push({
        'code' : 1,
        'abbreviation' : 'ene',
        'description' : 'ENERO'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 2,
        'abbreviation' : 'feb',
        'description' : 'FEBRERO'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 3,
        'abbreviation' : 'mar',
        'description' : 'MARZO'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 4,
        'abbreviation' : 'abr',
        'description' : 'ABRIL'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 5,
        'abbreviation' : 'may',
        'description' : 'MAYO'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 6,
        'abbreviation' : 'jun',
        'description' : 'JUNIO'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 7,
        'abbreviation' : 'jul',
        'description' : 'JULIO'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 8,
        'abbreviation' : 'ago',
        'description' : 'AGOSTO'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 9,
        'abbreviation' : 'sep',
        'description' : 'SEPTIEMBRE'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 10,
        'abbreviation' : 'oct',
        'description' : 'OCTUBRE'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 11,
        'abbreviation' : 'nov',
        'description' : 'NOVIEMBRE'
    });
    array.push({
        'code' : 12,
        'abbreviation' : 'dic',
        'description' : 'DICIEMBRE'
    });

    return array;

}
```

Comment: Como quieres que te muestre esos 3 campos(code,abbrevation,description) en el select? según tengo entendido el select solo muestra el Value, y el Text, y segun la documentación de [Select2](https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays) el Value se representa por el parametro id y el Text por text.